# Is it possible to say that if a A is a set of elements of a semigroup S, there exists some other semigroups on the alphabet A?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

Suppose we have a finite semigroup, its element's set is `A = {1,2,...n}`, can we get some other semigroups whose element's set is **A** too ?

Comment: Yes, as long as we have more than one element we can clearly define many semigroup structures on any set.

Comment: Is there any algorithm (I have the Cayley's table of a semigroup and I want to get all semigroup's tables on the same set of elements) ?

Comment: I don't think there is any algorithm that can deal with sets of more than a few elements without taking forever.

Comment: My table is small, it is  5x5 matrix

Comment: You haven't made it clear whether you really  want all semigroups, or just all semigroups up to isomorphism.

Comment: I want to count all semigroups.

Comment: There are $1915$  semigroups of order $5$ up to isomorphism, which I believe are available in GAP. I would be inclined to take each of these in turn and, for each of them, try all $120$ permutations of the five elements, some of which may be equal. This will give at most (in fact less than) $1915 \times 120 = 229800$ possible multiplication tables, and enumerating them should take long.

Comment: As a side comment, note that 229,800 minutes is around 5-1/2 months. If you worked non-stop for 12 hours a day, it would take you about a year, working at break-neck speed with perfect accuracy. If creating and checking each table took longer-like 10 minutes or so, this single task would consume a decade. No time for meal breaks, either. Realistically, doing this "by hand" would probably consume a lifetime. You would most likely have to hand off the task of checking the semigroups of order 6 to your descendents.

Comment: Now I am confused. I got the number 1915 from the online encyclopaedia of integral sequences https://oeis.org/A027851 but the GAP library http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/smallsemi-0.6.10/doc/chap1.html#X85A08CF187A6D986 is giving different numbers - just 1160 for order 5. I expect someone can explain this!

Comment: @DerekHolt I saw it today. I found a [paper](http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume76/number6/pxc3890725.pdf) which gives a bit efficient algorithm for calculating number of semigroups of order 5, here the result is 183732, but OEIS says that it's 1915.

Comment: The discrepancy between the numbers 183732 and 1915 is clearly caused by the difference between working up to isomorphism or not.

Comment: Well, all is clear, but how to compute manually, I want my computer to compute for **n=5**, but it doesn't seem to be possible (I wrote a code in C, but it computes for n<=3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1160 is the number of semigroups of order $5$ up to isomorphism or anti-isomorphism. Anyway, the following GAP code does what you want if a few seconds.

```
LoadPackage("smallsemi");
S5 := SymmetricGroup(5);
allsg := [];
for i in [1..1160] do
  Print("Processing semigroup number ",i,"\n");
  s := SmallSemigroup(5, i);
  ls := List(s);
  #construct multiplication table of this semigroup.
  table := List(ls, x -> List(ls, y -> Position(ls,x*y)));
  tabs := [];
  for g in S5 do
    #Apply g to rows and columns of table to get isomorphic semigroup
    Add(tabs, List([1..5], x -> List([1..5], y -> table[x^g][y^g]^(g^-1))));
  od;
  #remove duplicates
  tabs := Set(tabs);
  #see if opposite semigroup is in list - if not add it and images under S5
  otable := TransposedMat(table);
  if not otable in tabs then
    tabs := Concatenation(tabs, List(tabs, x->TransposedMat(x)));
  fi;
  allsg := Concatenation(allsg, tabs);
od;
```

After running this, we get, as expected:

```
gap> Length(allsg);     
183732
```

Comment: Thank you, It's all I wanted to find, but what's the language? Is there the same code on C/C++ ?

Comment: The language is GAP: http://www.gap-system.org/ The advantage of using it is that there is a library package containing all of the $1160$ semigroups of order $5$ up to equivalence under isomorphism and anti-isomorphism. As you can see, starting from this library, the complete list of all $183732$ multiplication tables can be constructed in just a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you, I wish it isn't hard to work with GAP .

Comment: @DarekHolt could you please explain me a few things? Why are we creating symmetric groups? SymmetricGroup(5);

Comment: Two semigroup multiplication tables on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ are isomorphic semigroups if and only if there is a bijection from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to itself - that is, an element of $S_5$ -  which maps one table to the other. In this code we are going in the other direction. We start with a set of representatives of the equivalence classes of semigroups (but up to isomorphism or anti-isomorphism) and apply eleemnts of $S_5$ to get all of the distinct multiplication tables. By transposing the table, we get an anti-isomorphic semigroup.

Comment: So if I'd like to change the code for computing the number of semigroups for some other n (for instance n = 6,7,8), what changes I have to do here?

Comment: You need to replace $1160$ by $15973$, $836021$, and $1843120128$ when $n=6,7$ and $8$ respectively. But I expect you will run out of memory when $n=8$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to understand the code in more detail today. But I'm new at GAP so maybe I'll have a few questions.